# Ordinal numbers list latex

Tags: numbering, lists, enumerate

I'm looking for a way to create an ordinal numbers list in latex. Can i use the enumerate statement to do this?

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `enumitem` package to customize the labels of an `enumerate` list. The degree symbol can be found in the `textcomp` package. In the MWE below `\arabic*` means "the arabic (=normal number) version of the item counter".

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{textcomp} % for the degree symbol
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*\textdegree.]
\item first item
\item second item
\item third item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hello @Marjin thank you a lot for your great solution. If I want to replace ° with the character 'a', which part of the code should  i change?

Comment: Then you remove `\textdegree` and you put an `a` there. In that case you can also remove `\usepackage{textcomp}` because that is only needed for the degree symbol.

Comment: For a superscript _a_ it is `label=\arabic*\textsuperscript{a}.`.

Comment: perfect additional explanation @Marijn